# JPA one to one relation retrieves entity with null property

Tags: hibernate, jpa, relationship, spring-data

I have two JPA entities like:

```
public class Request{

    @OneToOne
    private User user;
    private Date submitted;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="id.request", optional=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Appointment;
}

public class Appointment{
    @EmbeddedId
    private AppointmentId id;

    public static class AppointmentPk{
        @OneToOne
        private Request request;
        private LocalDate date;
    }
}
```

Then I make the JPQL query (using **spring data**):

```
SELECT r.appointment, r FROM Request r INNER JOIN FETCH r.appointment a
```

I have a list of arrays as result valorized as:

- array[0]: The right appointment
- array[1]: The request with the `appointment` property `null`

It seems impossible to have `appointment` property valorized in the `Request` retrieved from the queries...What I miss??